# How to show different fonts for different data labels in pie / doughnut chart using Python > xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Using python and xlsxwriter I want to output a doughnut chart where I can hardcode some data labels in a white font, but other data labels in a black font. I would include images, but since I am new here, I apparently can't :( 
To avoid confusion: if my doughnut chart is divided into 4 equal segments, by data labels I mean the 4 labels that say "25%" and are each placed in the center of their respective quarter of the doughnut chart.

My point is that when I have a segment of the doughnut chart with a light background color, I want to be able to code a black font data label (so that it's easily readable), and vice versa with a segment of the doughnut chart that has a dark background color (white font on top of dark background).

So far, I've tried using the chart series option "data_labels" a first time at the "add_series" level in order to set the main format for my data labels, and then within each of the "points" in my doughnut chart, I tried including a different version of the "data_labels" option (see code below). Can someone please tell me why this isn't working?

Just FYI: in the code below I use a pandas df (that I generate in the script from a list of lists), but even if this is inefficient right now, I'm doing this so that the next version of the script can read data from an existing (and much bigger) pandas df.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

# initialize list of lists
data = [['Tom', 10], ['Jerry', 15], ['Julie', 14], ['Amy', 12], ['Tony', 13]]

# Create pandas df
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Apples'])

# Write everything to an excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df_new.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Create a new chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'doughnut'})

# Add a series to the chart.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6',
                  'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6',
                  'data_labels': {'value': True, 'font':{'size': 12, 'color': 'white', 'bold': True}, 'legend_key': True},
                  'points': [
                        {'fill': {'color': '#B7DEE8'}, 'data_labels': {'value': True, 'font':{'size': 12, 'color': 'black', 'bold': True}, 'legend_key': True}},
                        {'fill': {'color': '#FAC090'}, 'data_labels': {'value': True, 'font':{'size': 12, 'color': 'black', 'bold': True}, 'legend_key': True}},
                        {'fill': {'color': '#604A7B'}},
                        {'fill': {'color': '#4A452A'}},
                        {'fill': {'color': '#011f4b'}},
                  ],
                  })

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('D1', chart)

workbook.close()

writer.save()
print('Finished')
```

Anyhow, I'd really appreciate any help!